# make Squid invisible to 3rd party filters

Tags: linux, proxy, filter, squid

I have my Squid proxy server up and running on CentOS 5.5 with a minimal config and without authentication to bypass internet filtering, it works fine but surprisingly [`whatismyip.com`](http://www.whatismyip.com/) detects my proxy which is completely a bad idea! it also detects my Squid's version and reveals my real IP address!! :

```
Your IP Address Is: 91.99.X.X
Other IPs Detected: 209.54.X.X
Possible Proxy Detected: 1.1 server.3p3r.com:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE21)
```

Where did I go wrong? is there anything I can do to make Squid invisible to these 3rd party filters and proxy detection scripts?

Any resources would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid adds X-Forwarded-For header into request.
If your Squid version is 3.1 or newer you may set "forwarded_for" option to "delete".

Comment: Yep, noticed that, but I think it's only a little part of the problem. Squid leaves some footprint too.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the etc/squid/squid.conf file:

```
via off

forwarded_for off

request_header_access Allow allow all 

request_header_access Authorization allow all 

request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all 

request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all 

request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all 

request_header_access Cache-Control allow all 

request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all 

request_header_access Content-Length allow all 

request_header_access Content-Type allow all 

request_header_access Date allow all 

request_header_access Expires allow all 

request_header_access Host allow all 

request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all 

request_header_access Last-Modified allow all 

request_header_access Location allow all 

request_header_access Pragma allow all 

request_header_access Accept allow all 

request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all 

request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all 

request_header_access Accept-Language allow all 

request_header_access Content-Language allow all 

request_header_access Mime-Version allow all 

request_header_access Retry-After allow all 

request_header_access Title allow all 

request_header_access Connection allow all 

request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all 

request_header_access User-Agent allow all 

request_header_access Cookie allow all 

request_header_access All deny all
```